# указатель this от временного объекта

Tags: c++, указатели

есть такой надуманный класс для примера

```
class Example
{
public:
  int x = 0;
  Example& get_ref()
  {
    return *this;
  }
};
```

такая строчка естественно вызывает ошибку, так как берем неконстантную ссылку на rvalue

```
Example& example = Example();
```

но почему такой пример не вызывает ошибок и мы можем даже менять состояние по этой ссылке, если это тоже самое? (или не тоже самое?)

```
Example& example = Example().get_ref();
```

и каким образом указатель `this` берет адрес временных объектов? я себе представлял это так под капотом `Example* this = &(объект вызывающий метод)` и не задумывался особо, так как никогда не вызывал методы от rvalue или вызывал и не думал об этом...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а какая сущность в итоге к еxample присваивается во втором примере которую мы можем менять даже?

Comment: кажется я не понял о чем вы. Вас смущает, что временный объект может вызывать свой метод, который возвращает ссылку на него?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan да это смущает и еще то что `example` можно менять по этой ссылке или это уже UB?

Comment: как можно менять, если после выражения он не существует?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan могу обращаться к `example.x` но да я уже понял что это все таки UB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во втором примере временный объект сразу же удаляется, потому если дальше работать со ссылкой, то будет UB.

> каким образом указатель `this` берет адрес временных объектов?

Ну просто берет. Невозможность напрямую взять адрес rvalue<sup>1</sup> - это защита от дурака, искусственное ограничение.

---

Еще, полезно понять разницу между *объектами* и *выражениями*.

*Объект* создается во время выполнения (где-то в памяти), а *выражение* - это надпись в коде, ссылающаяся на этот объект.

Вот вы выполнили `Example().get_ref();`, и в памяти создался временный объект. Выражение `Example()` ссылается на этот объект, и это выражение является rvalue.

Внутри метода `get_ref()`, выражение `*this` ссылается на тот же самый объект, это выражение является lvalue.

Категории (lvalue/rvalue/...) есть только у выражений, у объектов их нет. Адреса есть у всех объектов<sup>2</sup>, даже у временных.

---

<sup>1</sup> Точнее, взять адрес xvalue. У prvalue адреса как такового нет, но его можно [материализовать](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) в xvalue, у которого адрес есть. У вас prvalue `Example()` материализуется, когда на нем дергают метод.

<sup>2</sup> Тут можно поспорить, а что есть объект в регистре? Стандарт разрешает получить адрес любого объекта (даже временного - но не напрямую, а например внутри метода, как вы сделали). Для вас все объекты как будто бы находятся в памяти. Компилятор может засовывать их в регистры только по [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) - то есть если компилятор решил поместить объект в регистр, то он должен делать это незаметно для вас.

Comment: спасибо! открыли глаза на происходящее, нужно поизучать

Answer (score 1):

Выражением  `Example& example = Example();` вы ссылаетесь на несуществующий объект, то есть левый операнд есть ссылка, а правый _ объект. А в выражении:

```
Example& example = Example().get_ref();
```

И первое и второе выражение есть ссылки, поэтому это не то же самое и не является ошибкой. Другое дело, что объекта нет после этого выражения. Ну это как бы то же самое, что написать:

```
Example* pex = new Example;
Example& example = *pex; // *pex тоже является ссылкой на объект
delete pex;
```

Как вы понимаете, после этого кода ссылка становится недействительной

Comment: получается метод `get_ref` возвращает возвращает ссылку из памяти где временные переменные хранятся в течении выражения?

Comment: получается, что `Example().get_ref()` и есть ссылка, такая же, как и  `example`  вашем примере